# How to call GenericModelViews with arguments from another view?

Tags: django, django-views, django-generic-views

### I want to return GenericDeleteView with arguments from another view.

I have a view, that gets an pk of an object and I want to delete it using `Django` generic DeleteView subclass.

The problem is that the pk can be of **different Models**.

I have the respective GenericDeleteViews defined and if I add them to urls.py and trigger them from there with positional argument, everything works fine. But I would like something little different.

Example of what I would want:

*views.py*

```
def delete_object_view(request, pk):
if FirstModel.objects.filter(pk=pk).exists():
    return FirstModelDeteleView.as_view()(request, !!pk!!)
else:
    return SecondModelDeleteView.as_view()(request, !!pk!!)
```

But the case is that this does not pass the pk to the DeleteView and it returns the error: 
*Generic delete view must be called with either an object pk or a slug*

I tried many alternatives, passing `kwargs={'pk':pk}` and some other, but nothing seems to be working.

I am desperate and even tough I know some workarounds, this sounds like something that should be possible, and seems elegant.

Thanks for **any advice**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I will not follow your approach in calling another view from a view. (i find it is not elegant solution)
>
> I have not test this answer, so you may need to debug some minor errors later.

Because your `DeleteView` may use different `Model`, then you may want to determine the `Model` dynamically.

You still could use the generic [`DeleteView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.DeleteView). Since it uses the [`SingleObjectMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin), instead of specifying the [`model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.model) in the View, you should then overwrite [`get_queryset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_queryset) method or [`get_object`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object) method.

Sample code:

```
class MyDeleteView(DeleteView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        if FirstModel.objects.filter(pk=<pk>).exists():
            return FirstModel.objects.all()
        else:
            return SecondModel.objects.all()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. 

Just to clarify to other people, you give the <pk> parameter to objects.filter function from DeleteView as so:

`Model.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs.get(self.pk_url_kwarg))`

And in the template use {{ object.<attribute> }} to access the models attributes.

Comment: yup, something like that.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse):

You should use the `reverse()` urlresolver.

Try this:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

    if FirstModel.objects.filter(pk=pk).exists():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('first_model_delete',kwargs={'pk' : pk})
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('second_model_delete',kwargs={'pk' : pk})
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. 

The problem with this solution is that you end up having an url, which has a view that has to decide an then redirect to the specific delete_url of a Model. That way you end up with three different urls..

Comment: You're right, with this solution you need 3 different url.